# Strange Url's in ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net

My asp.net 4 website url format is `http://www.somesite.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=3330`

but it sometimes gets changed to

```
http://www.somesite.com/(S(ghtef0vy5fgfdjgdfgderd55)X(1))/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=3330
```

or

```
http://www.somesite.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=3330&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=3330
```

How can i prevent this. I want all url's to be of this format only

```
http://www.somesite.com/ShowProduct.aspx?ID=3330
```

**UPDATE:**

I just saw that I have three entries

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/NoAccess.aspx" name="FORMAUTH"/>
        </authentication>
```

and

```
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
```

and

```
<anonymousIdentification cookieless="AutoDetect" enabled="false"/>
```

What disadvantage will it have if I remove cookieless. WIll it break earlier bookmarked urls? Also how should both the config entries be rewritten so that i use cookies?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a config that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="AutoDetect" timeout="20"/>
      </sessionState>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What you want is to remove the "cookieless" attribute so it defaults to "UseCookies"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx

Comment: I just updated my question. Will my app break in any way if I make this change. For eg: if a user has bookmarked a url will it break if I make this change?

Comment: I *believe* you can just remove the cookieless attributes completely; the default behavior is for cookies to be used across the board. RE: bookmarks...I'm not sure about that one, but you could always grab a rewriter and make sure they get routed back properly (http://urlrewriter.net/). Depending on your traffic, it might not be worth it though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the membership cookie settings for browsers, try looking under

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms ...>
```

And make sure that you have `cookies="userCookies"` set.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means you are using cookieless session storage, and ASP.net alters the url to keep track, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for appropriate web.config configuration.

Comment: I just updated my question. Is your answer still the same? thnks